# How to call a function with arguments from an html string which is defined as a variable in another function?

Tags: javascript

I have a function defined like this:

```
function chat_add_user_message(message, url, option_position, vote_count) {
    var html = '<div">' +
        '<p class="message" onclick="cast_vote()">' +
            message +
        '</p>' +
    '</div>';
    $(".chatlogs").append(html);
};
```

Now what I want to do is call the function `cast_vote` whenever the message is clicked. Also I want to pass arguments to this function.

I have tried calling the `cast_vote` function without arguments in the above example code. Although I had this function defined like here:

```
function cast_vote() {
    console.log("Cast Vote");
};
```

I got an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: cast_vote is not defined
>   at HTMLParagraphElement.onclick

How do I call the `cast_vote` function with arguments from `var html`?

Comment: can you share your html?

Comment: @Shashishekhar Hasabnis what arguments you wanna pass to it?

Comment: @MaheerAli the arguments  same for the function chat_add_user_message except for the first message argument

Comment: where do you define your function `cast_vote`, I can call it with no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your `cast_vote` is not on the top level. Functions referenced by inline handlers must be defined on the top level for them to be referenceable. For example, the following won't work:

```js
$(() => {
  function doStuff() {
    console.log('doing stuff');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="doStuff()">click me</div>
```

You'd have to move the function out onto the top level, so that it's in global scope:

```js
function doStuff() {
  console.log('doing stuff');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="doStuff()">click me</div>
```

So, you could move your `cast_vote` function to the top level. But, it would be better to avoid inline handlers entirely; they're pretty bad practice, and can make code harder to manage. Instead, attach the listener properly using Javascript. With jQuery, you can pass the function to `.click`:

```
function chat_add_user_message(message, url, option_position, vote_count) {
    var $newDiv = $(
    '<div>' +
        '<p class="message">' +
            message +
        '</p>' +
    '</div>'
    );
    $newDiv.find('p').click(cast_vote);
    $(".chatlogs").append(newDiv);
}
```

To pass additional arguments to `cast_vote`, you can instead pass a function that itself *calls* `cast_vote` to `click`:

```
$newDiv.find('p').click(() => cast_vote('arg1', 'arg2'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your chatlog class, have this

```
<div id="foo" style="display:none">
    <p class="message" onclick="cast_vote()"></p>'
</div>
```

Have url, option_position, vote_count as global variables in js so that you don't need to pass them as params.

```
function chat_add_user_message(message, url, option_position, vote_count) {
    $(".message").text(message);
    $("#foo").css({"display": "block"});
    $(this).url = url;
    $(this).option_position = option_position;
    $(this).vote_count = vote_count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `click` event handler from Javascript.

```
function chat_add_user_message(message, url, option_position, vote_count) {
    var div = $("<div>"); //Create <div> element
    var p = $("<p>"); //Create <p> element
    $(p).addClass("message") //Add message css class
        .text(message) //set the text inside the <p> element
        .appendTo(div); //append <p> to <div>

    //Define click event handler
    $(p).click(function(){
        cast_vote(message, url, option_position, vote_count);
    });

    //Append <div> to .chatlogs
    $(".chatlogs").append(div);
};

function cast_vote(message, url, option_position, vote_count) {
    console.log(message, url, option_position, vote_count);
};

chat_add_user_message("Hello World", "http://www.example.com", 0, 0);
chat_add_user_message("Hello World 2", "http://www.example.com", 1, 1);
```